# @javascriptinterface API level < 17

Tags: java, javascript, android, annotations, backwards-compatibility

For my Android app I have set an eclipse project build target of 4.2 (API 17), android:minSdkVersion="11" and android:targetSdkVersion="17". As I want to use some Java functions from my Javascript code, it's necessary to add the @javascriptinterface annotation to these functions.

Is it possible to run the app with an Android API < 17 although the @javascriptinterface annotation is not known in these versions?